# Combine initial Observable with an Observable for changes (into a single Observable)

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have two observables. One that fetches the initial data, and another one that should react to changes and applay them accordingly:

```
const initial$: Observable<Report[]>;
const changes$: Observable<ObjectChangeEvent<Report>>;
```

Some characteristics are:

1. initial$ has to complete first, before changes can be applied
2. changes$ can emit 0..n times
3. the changed array should be the basis for the next change emit. That means only the first change should apply to the initial State. Following changes should not discard previous ones.

I want to combine both observables into a single one. The closest I've come so far, is the *combineLatest* Operator. But it conflicts with characteristic 2), as *changes$* may not emit anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean somehting like this:

```
this.result$ = this.changes$.pipe(
  skipUntil(this.initial$),
  // ...
);
```

Or...

```
const initial$: Observable<Report[]>;
const changes$: Observable<ObjectChangeEvent<Report>>;

const accumulatedChanges$: Observable<ObjectChangeEvent<Report>[]>;

this.accumulatedChanges$ = this.changes$.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
  startWith([]),
); // emits [change1], [change1, change2], [change1, change2, change3]....

this.result$ = combineLatest([this.initial$, this.accumulatedChanges$]).pipe(
  // apply all accumulated changes on initial
);
```

---

**Edit:**

OR....

```
this.result$ = this.initial$.pipe(
  switchMap(initial => this.changes$.pipe(
    // applyChangeToCurrent is only a placeholder for your semantic to alter the current
    scan((current, change) => applyChangeToCurrent(current, change), initial),
  )),
);
```

Comment: Does combineLatest really fit here? It requires every observable to emit at least once, which is not given for "changes$".

"scan" seems to be a good idea but I need to access the array somehow. I want to build a new array with the previous array and a ObjectChangeEvent. For example if an object got deleted, the new array should have one less item.

Comment: You could add a `startWith` after scan to force 1 emition. I added it in my example

Comment: Your third approach works if both observables emit at least once. So I had to add "startsWith" to "changes$". I decided to use "concat(initial$, changes$).pipe(scan(...));" You gave me the right direction, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the first requirement you can use [`last`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html) operator, combining with [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to switch to the `changes$` observable and using the last value of `initial$` in it.
Using [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) operator using it as initial state in case `changes$` is empty.

Generally it should look something like this:

```
initial$.pipe(
  last(),
  mergeMap(initialState =>
    changes$.pipe(startWith(initialState))
  )
);
```